# Problemas com o posicionamento do dialog do primefaces

Tags: css, primefaces

Queria saber uma forma de posicionar meu `dialog` a uma certa distancia do lado esquerdo da tela.

```
<p:dialog id="dialogAcesso" showHeader="false" visible="true" width="500" position="left">



            <div align="center">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="7">                        
                    <h:commandButton type="submit" id="Enviar" value="Enviar" action="#{servidorMB.alterarUsuario()}" style="border-width:0px; text-align: center; border-radius: 5px; height: 29px; width: 70px;  background: #427BCA; color: #ffffff"/>
                    <h:commandButton type="submit" id="voltar" value="Voltar" action="#{servidorMB.alterarUsuario()}" style="border-width:0px; text-align: center; border-radius: 5px; height: 29px; width: 70px;  background: #427BCA; color: #ffffff"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </div>
            <p:spacer width="100" height="15" />
        </p:dialog>
```

O `position="left"` apenas cola ele do lado esquerdo porem queria uma certa distancia do canto esquerdo como faço ?

Comment: Coloca no CSS margin-left:20px por exemplo

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema com a tag position="x,y"

Comment: Considere então se "auto responder" colocando a solução com detalhes para ajudar quem cair ai procurando uma resposta :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir solucionar o problema configurando a tag `position`

Como por exemplo:

```
 <p:dialog id="dialogAcesso" showHeader="false" visible="true" width="500" height="400" position="230,130" >
```